# android ndk practices

Tags: android, testing, android-ndk, google-tv

Now with the release of new android NDK, given the fragmentation of android devices, what testing measures one should employ to test over different phones, tablets and/or google tv based devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you use the NDK, you will only be able to target certain versions of Android. Basic rule is, the simpler the code, the later the version of Android will run it. See the documentation in the NDK and the Android source code for specifics on this. Don't always trust the (scarce) documentation though - read the source code when in doubt. It helps a lot.

That said, a testing policy must include what will be tested, so:

- Step 1: Based on your code, decide on which version of Android you *can*
  support.
- Step 2: Find out which devices you *must* target, and which devices you *want* to target.
- Step 3: Make the matrix of device/Android version available and what you *can* support, for the *must* category.
- Step 4: Based on your investment policy, repeat step #3 for the *want* category.
- Step 5: Get the devices and setup a testing structure.

And, finally, to answer your question:
The problem isn't the testing, the problem is deciding what to support. Good testing measures include testing all the devices you target and provide support for. Excellent testing measures adds the devices you run on, but don't support.

Comment: I would love to see Rovios mobile architecture/build/deployment and how they solved these problems.

Comment: We build for AIX, Linux (several CPU types), iOS, Mac OS, Windows (several types), Windows CE (several types), to name a few. The trick is to have precise abstractions in the code, a killer build system, a process for people to do testing, translation, localization etc. and a killer system to support that. We made our tools for these things ourselves, mostly using scripting. It enables us to push new binaries out for testing and translation in 20 minutes, to 30+ product managers, for all platforms. So the problem is solvable, but you need to focus on process, then make simple automation.